# Accessing array of strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

How do I access the letters `a` in `arm` and `c` in `candy` for the following array of strings?

Basically, I am a newbie in C and would like to see how to access a particular character in array of strings
I define the array using the following code:
`const char *str1[] = {"arm","candy"}`

Comment: 1) Read a book. 2) Try some code with a compiler. 3) Ask on SO if you get stuck. In that order.

Comment: Something like `str1[0][0]`

Answer (score 3):

The below code gives you **"a" in arm**.

```
str1[0][0];
```

---

The below code gives you **"c" in candy**.

```
str1[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what you have is an array of arrays so:

```
char c = str1[0][1]; // value of c would be thr 'r' from arm
```